# Passing argument to method in XAML with Caliburn Micro [WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'd like to pass an argument in all my buttons to specify which button is clicked.

Right now I cant come further than:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="24,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Background="#FFE5E5E5" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" content="Details...&#xD;&#xA;">
           <i:Interaction.Triggers>
             <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                              <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="ShowColumnDetailsView" />
              </i:EventTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions

Comment: @Aybe Thank you for your response. The link however, does only provide a solution when I have one button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you could do the following:

```
    <Button Content="Click Me" x:Name="MyButton">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="SayHello">
                    <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=MyButton}" />
                </cal:ActionMessage>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

Or did I miss something in the process?

Comment: Ah so you pass the actual button name. And what should the method accept then?

Comment: (I was trying to pass an integer value maybe or a stringname, but this is fine too)

Comment: I believe it should be `void SayHello(Button button)`, if you get `null` then try `object` temporarily to spot what's really passed in while debugging.

Comment: Thank you very much, after some debugging it worked perfectly. It is indeed a Button.